# ParseException When Reading Date from File

Tags: java, parse-error

I am trying to create an object with data the program reads out of a text file. The data was put into the text file by the same program. I'm splitting the lines, then sticking each segment into a String ArrayList. It's been working well until I get to the date. Parsing the String date to a Date type results in a ParseException error. Any ideas why I'm not parsing it correctly? Thank you!

```
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader("open_tickets.txt"));
String line = bufReader.readLine();    
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null){
        String[] split = line.split("= ");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
            words.add(split[i]);
            if (split[i].endsWith("2015")){
                String arrayPriority = words.get(1); //"5"
                String description = words.get(3); //"Building on fire"
                String reportedBy = words.get(5); //"Tim"
                String arrayDate = words.get(7); //"Mon Mar 02 13:31:24 CST   
2015"


                int priority = Integer.valueOf(arrayPriority); //5
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE MM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
                try {
                    Date date = formatter.parse(arrayDate);

                } catch (ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

StackTrace: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Mar 02 13:31:24 CST 2015"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at ----.company.Main.addTicketFromFile(Main.java:257)
    at ----.company.Main.main(Main.java:17)

```
public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
{
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    Date result = parse(source, pos);
    if (pos.index == 0)
        throw new ParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + source + "\"" ,
            pos.errorIndex);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well `Mon Mar 02 13:31:24 CST 2015` is not in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: @gtgaxiola Just noticed that, corrected, still returned error. Edited to add stacktrace.

Comment: @Michelle your SimpleDate Format is still incorrect. Month for example should be `MMM` to parse `Mar`

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```